# How can I prevent foreign objects appearing in a FB Places graph call?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, location

I am confounded to find objects without any real link in my facebook graph calls. Say I make a call of places near a point in Denmark Europe. Along the list of results, I can risk to get items from singapore, korea, Austin TX and other completely off positions. But according to the FB result, the coordinates are matching.

Take this call for example :

[FBGraph call, Center : 55.676127,12.581892 (Copenhagen, Denmark) , Distance : 1000m](https://graph.facebook.com/search?limit=20&type=place&center=55.676127,12.581892&distance=1000&format=json&access_token=BAAFszu0TZB30BAE239nOyVcFZCHlZAL8ktqsejJTY8qxsTFtGrH7uXCEZByTDW7C3N1YpyFj3088ZCr0B7wkBU8Rb94CtMvjMBOKVgUYyhVgGY5ZBFFB8xZAUXFAN8cl2ej7HjGNTKQf5PDHHYJ8p3Wf19iNZCV3Th8mZC9BuFXU5DTIgb3Ip9WmAzuy5kghMYOABlmDfemtNZB8x1uQK0eQZCz2ZCiGxBmf0drna8Q1J9szbQZDZD)

Here are some expected results:

```
    {
             "name": "Fortunen Bar & Spiseri",
             "location": {
                "street": "Ved Stranden 18",
                "city": "K\u00f8benhavn",
                "country": "Denmark",
                "zip": "1061",
                "latitude": 55.677747326448,
                "longitude": 12.5802503332
             },
             "category": "Local business",
             "id": "454633487897742"
          },
```

And suddently, a result that confuses me to the core :

```
      {
         "name": "CampusFrance Hong Kong",
         "location": {
            "street": "25/F, Tower II, Admirality Centre,18, Harcourt Road, Central, ",
            "city": "Hong Kong",
            "country": "Hong Kong",
            "latitude": 55.67758,
            "longitude": 12.58226
         },
         "category": "Government organization",
         "id": "206130582769483"
      },
```

I know i could filter them out with some name comparison on the Location country, but when people are close to borders, it would mess up my result, and also, if I request 20 items, i would risk ending up with 19 or 18, but still have a possible next page...

Anyone know of a flag or something one can set to avoid this ?

Comment: That Hong Kong entry has bad data.  The long/lat matches Denmark.  Might have been entered by a user with a GPS bug or someone was actually in Denmark and created a bogus Place.  I guess if you are close to a border, you can calculate the top countries and reject all other country strings.  Eg. if you are on the border of France/Germany, you'll see 50% of places with France and 50% with Germany; then you can reject all other country strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Donn Lee mentions, this was a individual glitch. We are not sure why Facebook believes this entry is in Denmark, but its clear that it does not belong there.